# Writing post values to a text file

Tags: php, post, fwrite

I am trying to append a string to a text file.

The file `users.txt` is in the same folder as the php file.

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];

$message = "name is :" . $fname. "\n";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ( file_exists("users.txt")) {
        $fp = fopen ("users.txt", "a");
        fwrite($fp, $message);
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert("file does not exist")</script>';
    }
}
```

**It is not throwing the message error, nor is it writing to the file**.
What have I done wrong?

My form:

```
<form onsubmit="return ValidateInputs();" action="contact.php" method="post"  id="contactForm" >
          <input class="input" type="text"  name="fname" id="fname"  />
          <input    type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"  />
</form>
```

nb. this form does submit.. it will send the message to me in an email.

Comment: First step: Is your submit button named? As in `<input type="submit" name="submit">`

Comment: Be sure that the file permissions of `user.txt` is set to 777.

Comment: @Skippy Try Ali Gajani's answer below.

Comment: Is the script on Windows or Linux?

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 users.txt`

Comment: @Skippy change the answer below from `w` to `a` if you plan on using it. You can also use the `a+` switch, which will change the order it is written to.

Comment: @DummyCode Not all servers require a file that's being written to, necessarily need `777` permissions. Using `777` poses a higher security risk then `644`, however in certain cases, `777` has to be used, but that's most unlikely. All the servers I administer, which are not all hosted with the same service, require `644`.

Comment: @Skippy I understand. Just showing potential risks in setting permissions to `777`. If that's not the case with you, then you use `644` safely. R-w-X on all 3 groups, X-execute ;-) the last one you don't want potential intruders to execute.

Comment: @Skippy: Your code work fine with me. I think no problem in your code.

Comment: @Skippy Have a look at `chmod` on Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod - this should help you to understand and get a feel of what it does.

Comment: @Skippy Is your code working after all, and if so, what was the problem?

Comment: @Skippy Post your form in an edit.

Comment: @Skippy Figured it out, see my answer.

Comment: @Skippy There is no way that your code could have worked without the `fname` being defined. Using / adding permissions would have not done any good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your PHP handler is that the `fname` variable was not defined.

This was added `$fname=$_POST['fname'];`

```
<?php

$fname=$_POST['fname'];

$message = "name is :" . $fname . "\n";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ( file_exists("users.txt")) {
        $fp = fopen ("users.txt", "a");
        fwrite($fp, $message);
        fclose($fp);

echo "Success";

    } 

else {
       echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert("file does not exist")</script>';
    }
}

?>
```

---

**Footnote**: Additional permissions may be required in order to write contents to file. `CHMOD 644` is usually the standard permissions setting, however certain servers require `777`.

Via FTP and if there's a window where you can manually type in a command, by  typing in `chmod 644 users.txt` or `chmod 777 users.txt` in your FTP software used.

Additional information on how to `chmod` files, may be obtained by visiting the GoDaddy Web site for Windows-based hosting services.

- **http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6481/setting-directory-permissions-with-windows-hosting-accounts**

---

Comment: @Skippy It's always to post full code. It's very hard to say where the problem can be. But I did have more questions to ask if all my questions had failed to find a solution.

Comment: @Skippy Does the file exist to start with? Because it won't write to it if it doesn't.

Comment: @Skippy Do up a Pastebin file then.

Comment: @Skippy ok wait. I doubt I need the whole code. We just need to figure out why it won't write to it.

Comment: @Skippy No, doesn't help going to the site. Do you know if you're on a Windows or Unix server?

Comment: @Skippy Ok. Visit this http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6481/setting-directory-permissions-with-windows-hosting-accounts

Comment: @Skippy and try to login via FTP and if there's a window where you can manually type in a command, enter either `chmod 644 users.txt` or `chmod 777 users.txt`

Comment: @Skippy No problem, hopefully we can resolve this. And you're welcome. Just don't know how longer I can stay. My GF's giving me the eye ;-)

Comment: @Skippy Cool! Well let me know here how things work out. I'm sure it will work out for the better.

Comment: @Skippy Aahh well will ya lookah dat! thanks :) I'm glad I could be of help Skippy, cheers (*peace*)

Comment: @Skippy That one was a first time for me (here). All the best, and do keep me posted. Ciao

Answer (score 3):

This works completely on my localhost. I haven't recreated the full scenario with your HTML but it works now. Just remember to set the file permissions to read/write and also make sure you do it one step at a time. For example, start off with this code and make sure you get the file name file.txt with the text you wanted. Then take it to the next level by including the HTML bit.

```
<?php
$fname = "Skippy";
$message = "name is :" . $fname. "\n";
$file = 'file.txt';
$fd = fopen($file, "a");

if ($fd) { 
    fwrite($fd, $message . "\n");   
    fclose($fd); 
}

?>
```

Comment: OP needs append `a`, not `w`. That will overwrite contents.

Comment: Let me know if it helps. I am too sleepy and I will work on this again and get you a better answer. Keep in touch :)

Comment: @Skippy Do you have your form that we can see? and is your input named `fname`?

Comment: @Skippy: Set permissions to read/write on the files and it works. For example, see my edit.